Why would vue's ref not work with Set but work with interger
The watch function for the Set would not work. It would work normally with int.
If I change it from ref() to reactive() it would work.
Is this an expected behavior?
<script setup>
import { ref,watch,reactive } from 'vue'
const msg = ref('Hello World!')
const testSet = ref(new Set());
const testInt = ref(5)

watch([testSet],()=>{
  console.log(testSet.value);
})
watch([testInt],()=>{
  console.log(testInt.value);
})

const updateTestSet = ()=>{
    testSet.value.add(Math.random());
}
const updateTestInt = ()=>{
    testInt.value = Math.random();
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input v-model="msg" />
  <button @click="updateTestSet">TEST SET</button>
  <button @click="updateTestInt">TEST INT</button>
</template>


watch((testSet.value),()=>...... works

It is expected behavior, though perhaps not very intuitive behavior.
You might note that I had a completely different answer here before because I also got tripped up by it. Vue 3 has reactive support for Set's now, so calling the .add(..) method should trigger a change.
The problem is in the way you have defined your watch, as @fOURP already pointed out in a comment, you must watch the value of the ref, not the ref itself:
<template>
  <button @click="newRandom()">Random</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
  let numbers = ref(new Set());
  function newRandom() {
    numbers.value.add(Math.random())
  }

  watch([numbers], () => {
    console.log('Never fires..');
  });
  watch([numbers.value], () => {
    console.log('Does fire!');
  });
</script>


The first sentence is applicable to shallowRef, not ref. This is specific to how watch works without deep flag

@EstusFlask You're absolutely right! I had the two confused.

Thanks. I think I understand now. I read the doc many times and would never get this from it.
